# custom allocator for allocation from heap

Tags: c++, c++11

I written allocator with allocation from heap. I have some trouble with memory allocate. First allocation was successfull, but the next one  crashed by access violation. I can't understand where is my problem. There are code:

```
#define NOMINMAX
#include <Windows.h>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <sstream>
template<class T>
class HeapAllocator
{
private :
    HANDLE hHeap;
    size_t size;
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using Traits = std::allocator_traits<HeapAllocator<T>>;
    using size_type = std::size_t;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using pointer = T*;
    using const_pointer = const T *;
    using reference = T &;
    using const_reference = const T &;
    T * allocate(std::size_t n);
    pointer address(reference value) const { return  &value; }
    const_pointer address(const_reference value) const { return &value; }
    void deallocate(T * p, std::size_t n);
    size_type max_size() const  { return     std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max() / sizeof(T); }
    template<class U, class... Args>
    void construct(U* p, Args&&... args) { std::allocator<T>().construct(p, std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
    template<class U>
    void destroy(U* p) { std::allocator<T>().destroy(p); }
    HeapAllocator();
    ~HeapAllocator();
    template<class U>
    struct rebind 
    { 
        using other = HeapAllocator<U>;
    };
    template<class U>
    HeapAllocator(const HeapAllocator<U> & other) {}
};
template<class T>
HeapAllocator<T>::HeapAllocator()
{
    hHeap = HeapCreate(HEAP_CREATE_ENABLE_EXECUTE|
                   HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE,
                    1024, 0);
size = sizeof(T);
}
template<class T>
HeapAllocator<T>::~HeapAllocator()
{
    HeapDestroy(hHeap);
}
template<class T1, class T2>
bool operator==(const HeapAllocator<T1> &, const HeapAllocator<T2> &)     throw()
{
    return true;
}
template <class T1, class T2>
bool operator!=(const HeapAllocator<T1>&,
    const HeapAllocator<T2>&) throw() {
    return false;
}
template<class T>
T * HeapAllocator<T>::allocate(std::size_t n)
{
    void *p = nullptr;
     p = HeapAlloc(hHeap, 0, sizeof(T) * n);
    if (p == nullptr)
        std::cerr << GetLastError() << '\n';
    return reinterpret_cast<T *>(p);
}
template<class T>
void HeapAllocator<T>::deallocate(T *p, size_t n)
{
    HeapFree(hHeap, 0, p);
}
```

Comment: Your `operator==` claims that memory allocated by any instance of `HeapAllocator` can be deallocated by any other instance. But that's a lie, as each instance uses its own heap (at least, most of the time).

Comment: ... except that you haven't implemented a copy constructor or assignment operator for your class. The implicitly defined copy constructor simply copies all members, whereupon you end up with two instances holding the same heap handle, each thinking that it owns the handle. When one of them is destroyed, it takes the heap with it, leaving the other with a dangling handle. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)